# Can't find the activity or gang operations that will allow me to take control of territory in Loren Square, Steelport (Morning Star territory)

Tags: saints-row-the-third

I can't find the activity or gang operations that will allow me to take control of two territories in [Loren Square, Downtown Steelport](http://saintsrow.wikia.com/wiki/Loren_Square) ([Morning Star](http://saintsrow.wikia.com/wiki/Morningstar) territory). I've driven all over the place but I can't seem to find them.

The two territories are the only ones not colored in purple, in this screenshot of the Loren Square map:

[image]

Anyone know the location of the activities or gang operations?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found a map of gang operation locations - click to enlarge:
[image]
Source: http://saintsrow.wikia.com/wiki/Gang_Operation

The lower-right uncontrolled gang operation in my question is actually located in another territory (as seen in the [screenshot of the map in my question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q0CDy.png)). This is probably why I haven't found it by driving around. The middle one is a bit tricky as it is actually located on top of a high-rise building, so you'll need an aircraft to spot and attack the gang in there.

Answer (score 0):

Gang operations can be hard to find sometimes. I recommend you use an attack chopper to seafly away from the location, allowing the spawns to reset, then fly back.

Comb the location, not just the streets but the alleys and open spots as well. Look for large groups of enemies. Fly closer and don't attack any until you see the "Gang activity located prompt". When you start attacking the gang, make sure not to stray too far away or it could prevent you from finishing the gang and gaining the location.