# bugged out gang operation. Is there a fix?

Tags: saints-row-the-third

I have a 97% control of the morning star district. The last part I had left was a gang operation on a roof. I killed all of the gang members while inside of my vitol and got no credit for completing it. Is there anyway to reset/fix this? I have been playing the game single player only.

Comment: Are you 100% you're missing the gang operation? If you leave and return, does the gang spawn back?

Comment: Don't do these in the VTOL (or at least get out once they start).  The game's detection of hovering aircraft is pretty bad.  If you must use one to get there, jump out when you arrive.  I bet if you leave and come back (possibly save and reload?) the gang operation will respawn.

Comment: Related: [Can't find the activity or gang operations that will allow me to take control of territory in Loren Square, Steelport (Morning Star territory)](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/74870/4797)

Answer (score 2):

This can happen in several places in the game. The Luchadore's gang operation on the boat parked south of 3count also caused me a similar problem. At one point, I had the gang auto-respawning and I was shooting them as fast as they were appearing, but the entire operation was still counted as incomplete. The air-accessible gang operations are also quite tricky as Z distance (height) appears to be a consideration for whether or not you've run.

There's 2 ways to *start* a gang operation cleanup; get within a certain range (X, Y, Z axes) of the gang, or get within an outer boundary and start shooting them. Either way, if you leave that outer boundary once the the gang op is started (when all the red circles appear above them) it counts as a gang op abort.

As has already been mentioned, the only way to solve this is to leave the area and come back later.

Leaving the area will usually mean going to a different part of the city. There seems to be a 'memory' in game of certain areas that doesn't reset until you move to a new area of the map that requires the game to remember that in detail instead. I've parked a helicopter, been killed, spawned at a hospital 5 blocks away, gone back and the chopper was still there. From what I can tell, the memory of the city zone resets when you move to another of the 4 major city areas, but I can't explicitly confirm that.

Ironically enough, I've had a related issue when approaching photo op candidates. Once I sprinted up to them and dialed back too slowly, ending up pushing them out of the way. They get upset and run away! I run around the block, but they're still missing. I leave the area, come back and all is forgiven. Once I pressed the engage button in *just* the wrong spot and used the photo op as a human shield instead. I had to leave the area, come back, and then complete the photo op correctly.

So; I can confirm that Gang ops seem to work on a similar set of rules. If you leave the area and come back later, you'll be fine. The important thing to remember is that for the rooftop ones in particular, your height counts for proximity to the gang op just like X & Y coords. In point of fact, good practice is to get your height right before you close in. From my experience, the event can be triggered by X & Y proximity, then cancelled out by Z. Again, if that happens, it's not a permanent fail but you do have to get out of the area to come back and try again.

Answer (score 1):

You have to land on the roof or place of the gang operation and maybe even get out. it will show as complete.

Answer (score 0):

I've had this happen. I kill everyone on the roof and it doesn't give me credit even when I land on the roof afterwards. Just wait a while and come come back later; only this time kill the last person by landing on the roof, getting out, and shooting them. Also, it might not give you credit if anyone falls off the roof.